# Vector of lengths of all elements in a cell array?

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization

I have a cell array containing matrices. I would like to get a 1-D row vector of the lengths of every element in the cell array. Example:

```
a = {[1, 2], [1, 8], [5, 2, 4]};
% b = ...?
b == [ 2, 2, 3 ]
```

Is this possible without using a for loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) is your friend.

```
b = cellfun( @numel, a );
```

Comment: @WesleyTansey: If you require high performance, use `cellfun('length',a)` instead (no function handle).